# What's the correct way to override Devise registration route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

My route.rb file has this line:

```
devise_for :users,
           :controllers => { registrations: 'register' },
           :path => '',
           :path_names => {
               :sign_in => 'login',
               :sign_out => 'logout',
               :sign_up => 'register'
           }
```

`sing_in` and `sing_out` overriding works well, but `sing_up` doesn't.
If I visit `/register` I obtain an `uninitialized constant RegisterController`.

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm pretty new to Rails and I don't understand very well what that code do. It comes out from many search on Google...

---

### update 1

I follow also this official guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes#another-simple-way-to-do-the-same-thing

---

### update 2

Ok, I don't know way I added the `:controllers` params to the previous code, but after removed it

```
devise_for :users,
       :path => '',
       :path_names => {
           :sign_in => 'login',
           :sign_out => 'logout',
           :sign_up => 'register'
       }
```

And now if I run `rake routes | grep devise` on my console I got this:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)          devise/registrations#cancel
user_registration        POST   /                          devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration    GET    /register(.:format)   devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration   GET    /edit(.:format)            devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /                          devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /                          devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /                          devise/registrations#destroy
```

And as you can see now the route for the creation of a user is `POST /`, and I'm sure that this is not a good thing... right? And the major problem is here: `GET /`have to be the homepage and not the get-all-users-page.

may the `:path => ''` introduce errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the path_names param is what you should be doing. You can assign the controller methods using:

```
devise_scope :user do

  get '/logout',                  :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  post '/signin',                 :to => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session

end
```

Comment: Question is not about `login` and `logout` routes, they works well, and I found my solution at the end of this official page https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes.

Question is about registration routes...

Comment: anyway at your solution you should add a route for the GET /singin as this: `get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session`